# If $f$ surjects from $A$ to $B$ then there is a bijection $\phi$ from a subset of $A$ to $B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a set and let $ f: A \to B $ be a surjective function. Prove that there exists a subset $ C \subseteq A $ and a function $ \phi: C \to B $ such that $ \phi $ is bijective.

I did it by giving particular examples, giving $ A = \{1,2,3 \} $ and $ B = \{1,2 \} $ and the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}
 1& \text{ if } x=1 \\ 
 1& \text{ if } x=2 \\ 
 2& \text{ if } x=3 
\end{cases}$ it is clearly a surjective function. Now if $ C = A \setminus \{1 \} $ what is desired remains. Guiding me from particular examples, I thought to consider the set $ C $ of all the images that are repeated because the function is not necessarily injective, as in the previous example removing 1, since it repeated with 2. But I don't know if the idea is well and I don't know how to express that set either. I tried as follows, $ C = A\setminus \{f (a) = f (b) \wedge a \neq b \mid \forall a, b \in A \} $ but I don't know if it's ok. Help.

Comment: The idea is sound: for all $y\in B$, remove all but one preimages of $y$ in $A$. Although how you mathematically defined $C$ is not very clear to me. Can you utilize what I said to write $C$ in set notation?

Comment: Just as you thought to define the $ C $ I tried to define it that way, but it is not clear to me how to write it correctly in set notation. In that part of defining the $ C $ it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can’t actually *prove* it by giving examples; the best that you can do is illustrate the concept that you have in mind. You’ve already recognized that what you have to worry about are the elements $b\in B$ such that the set $\{a\in A:f(a)=b\}$ has more than one element. What if for each $b\in B$ you let $A_b=\{a\in A:f(a)=b\}$? You know that each of these sets is non-empty; why? Thus, from each of them you can single out an element $a_b$. (Of course when $A_b$ has only one element, that element will automatically be $a_b$. In the absence of any other information about $A$ there is no way to specify how the others are chosen.) Now use these elements $a_b$ to define a suitable $C$.

**Added:** I should probably mention that in general choosing the elements $a_b$ requires the axiom of choice, though in specific cases it may not be necessary.

Comment: By the way, another idea I have is that since $ f: A\to B $ is surjective there is $ h: B \to A $ injective. So the function $ \phi_p: B \to \phi_p (B) $ is bijective given by $ \phi_p (b) = h (b) $ $\forall  b \in B $ but notice that $ \phi_p (B) \subset A $ and the inverse is bijective and define $ C = \phi_p (B) $.

Comment: @AndreiAgamez: This works fine if you’ve already shown that there is an injective $h:B\to A$ whenever there is a surjective $f:A\to B$.

Comment: Suppose that f is surjective. We construct a function $ h: B  \to A $ such that $ f \circ h = I_B $. For this, let $ b \in B $. Since $ f $ is surjective, there exists $ a \in A $ such that $ f (a) = b $. This $ a $ cannot be unique, $ a_b $. We define $ h (b) = a_b $. This $ h: B \to A $ function is well defined. Also, if $ b \in B $, then $ f (h (b)) = f (a_b) = b $, which shows that $ f \circ h = I_B $ and with that it is easy to see that $ h $ it is injective. That's cool right?

Comment: @AndreiAgamez: For some $b$ there may be a unique $a$ such that $f(a)=b$. This is essentially what I was suggesting: for each $b\in B$ pick an $a_b\in A$ such that $f(a_b)=b$, let $C=\{a_b:b\in B\}$, and observe that the restriction of $f$ to $C$ is a bijection from $C$ to $B$.

Comment: It is clear to see that this function is surjective, by the condition that $ f (a_b) = b $. But I don't understand how to show that that is injective, suggestion for that?

Comment: @AndreiAgamez: That follows immediately from the fact that $|C\cap A_b|=1$ for each $b\in B$: $C$ contains exactly one element mapped to $b$ by $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the ideas and suggestions.

Comment: @AndreiAgamez: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define in $A$ the equivalence relation $a\sim a' \stackrel{(def.)}{\iff} f(a)=f(a')$.

**Claim**.
The map $\psi_f\colon (A/\sim)\to B$, defined by $\psi_f([a]_\sim):=f(a)$, is well-defined and bijective.

*Proof*.

- Good definition: $a'\in [a]_\sim \Rightarrow [a']_\sim= [a]_\sim \Rightarrow\psi_f([a']_\sim)=\psi_f([a]_\sim)=f(a)$;
- Surjectivity: by the surjectivity of $f$ and the definition of $\psi_f$, $\forall b\in B, \exists a\in A\mid b=f(a)=\psi_f([a]_\sim)$;
- Injectivity: $\psi_f([a]_\sim)=\psi_f([a']_\sim)\Rightarrow f(a)=f(a')\Rightarrow a\sim a'\Rightarrow [a]_\sim=[a']_\sim\space$.

$\Box$

Moreover, by the Axiom of Choice, there is a bijection $\varphi\colon (A/\sim)\to R$, where $R\subseteq A$ is a set of representatives (see e.g. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0oXD.png)). Therefore, your sought bijection is $\phi\colon R\space(\subseteq A)\to B$ defined by $\phi:=\psi_f\circ \varphi^{-1}$:

$\color{white}{............................}$ [image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it is very interesting and elegant. One doubt, could you tell me how you made that diagram of the composition of the functions at the end that you gave as an illustration.